# Error in FUN: Expected a recursive structure built of NULLs, lists and dependencies

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to make a template of some container because I need it a lot. The Id in my function is the id of selectInput so it will be easier for the backend. How do I resolve this error?
Error in FUN: Expected a recursive structure built of NULLs, lists and dependencies

```
simSettingCard <- function(title, id, size = 12, style = "style.css") {
  div(
    class = glue("card ms-depth-8 ms-sm{size} ms-xl{size}"),
    style = style,
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
      Text(variant = "xLarge", title, block = TRUE, class = "card-title"),
      selectInput(
        id,
        label = "mg/dl",
        choices = c(bg_waarde, NULL),
        selected = NULL
      ),
    )
  )
}

simSettingCard(
   "T-60",
   "bgvalue-60"
)
```

Comment: You might want to use [Shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same error and don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: I did a very ugly workaround. However I don't have access to the repo anymore. I'm still not sure on what the problem was. Sorry I can't help you